# Python: While Loop Check Throughout Loop if True

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a very simple problem: I have made a while loop, and in the middle of it, set the initial condition to false. This, however, does not stop the loop and runs entirely through, (somewhat obviously,) until it attempts to unsuccessfully go through again. Here is a simplified construction of what I have.

```
while(a):
    print("hi")
    a = False
    print("bye")
```

This returns:

```
hi
bye
```

Again I would like to only return `hi`; I want the loop to continually check if its satisfied.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use **break**?

Comment: If you want `a` checked in more places, you're going to have to insert code to explicitly check it in those places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

> > `return`, or `break`

```
while a:
    print('hi')

    a = False
    if not a:
        break

    print('bye')
```

In a function or loop, when something is `return`ed, the function or loop terminates. You could also `return True`, or `break` which is a specific way to 'break' out of a loop.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear. Rather than fill this page with a huge amount of code, I simplified, but, evidently, excessively so. Anyway, I have a function, within the while loop, and that is where the initial condition is changed. So its similar to the original with the only caveat that everything after the `while(a)`, is inside a function, so a `break` isn't an option, and I need both the function and the original loop to stop.

Comment: if i understand correctly then, use `return` inside your function. Whenever you return inside a function, the function is terminated, then, directly outside of your function, `break` out of the while loop, or `return` something from the while loop

Answer (score 1):

Since the condition is `true` to start with (by design), the body of the loop will execute at least once. The fact you do something in the body of the loop to make the loop condition false doesn't stop the current iteration. It just means there won't be a *next* iteration after this one is done.

So if you want to get out in the middle of the current iteration, then you need to use `break`, `return`, or something more sophisticated like @inspectorG4dget's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(a):
    print("hi")
    a = False
    if a:
        print("bye")
```

OR

```
while(a):
    for s in ["hi", "bye"]:
    if a:
        print(s)
    if someCondition:
        a = False
```